# GNOME configuration database type-inference

Tags: python, gnome, gconf

My desktop is GNOME and I am programmatically changing its settings via Python.

The database has simple value types, e.g. strings, ints, lists of strings, list of ints, ...

A simple CLI tool to manipulate the data is gconftool-2, which returns values for keys using the `--get` option.

I don't know to to infer the type from these values considering that I need to know the value when setting it back to something. Notice, in my schema, "8" is a string and 8 is an int, but they are both output as just 8 by gconftool-2.

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than invoking the command line tool, try using the `gconf` module included in the GNOME Python bindings:

```
>>> import gconf
>>> client = gconf.Client()
>>> # Get a value and introspect its type:
>>> value = client.get('/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color')
>>> value.type
<enum GCONF_VALUE_STRING of type GConfValueType>
>>> value.get_string()
'#FFFFFFFFDDDD'
```

For lists, you can introspect the list value type:

```
>>> value = client.get('/apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins')
>>> value.type
<enum GCONF_VALUE_LIST of type GConfValueType>
>>> value.get_list_type()
<enum GCONF_VALUE_STRING of type GConfValueType>
>>> value.get_list()
(<GConfValue at 0x159aa80>, <GConfValue at 0x159aaa0>, ...)
```

In general though, you should know the types of the keys you're manipulating and use the appropriate type specific access methods directly (e.g. `Client.get_string` and `Client.set_string`).

Comment: This sounds like a better, saner, more robust/sensible/clean approach for my Python scripting of gconf.. I'll report back if it fixes my issue with lists of ints, lists of strings..

Comment: Lists of strings give me this: <enum GCONF_VALUE_LIST of type GConfValueType> and I am not sure how to discern list of ints, etc. Example: (as you use gnome-terminal..) global/active_encodings

Comment: the enumeration values are provided as globals in the `gconf` module.  So you could do `if value.type == gconf.VALUE_STRING`: ...`

Comment: Oops.  I realised you were asking about lists in particular.  `value.get_list_type()` should tell you the type of the list values.  The reference documentation (C based) may help too: https://developer.gnome.org/gconf/stable/